# how to move opengl from windows to linux?

Tags: opengl

I want to transfer OpenGL application from Windows to Linux without using glut.
I made opengl app in linux and had to use glut, but I cant fit my aap in that environment.
Once again sory for my english. In C++
Where to find just opengl instructins for that?

Answer (score 1):

You provided very little information. First and foremost: How do you create your window and OpenGL context?

Plain Win32 / WGL API? Then you'll have to redo the whole thing using Xlib / GLX. This is a example program doing it on Linux / X11
https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/x11argb_opengl

However I recommend using some established GUI toolkit/framework, like Qt, GTK+ or wxWidgets.

Answer (score 1):

GLUT is just a tool library which makes using GL more comfortable. OpenGL should be the same both on Windows and on Linux, so all you need to do is install the header files (see the instruction manual for your flavor of Linux or tell us which you're using) and run the Makefile.

Comment: It's not exactly the same. On windows the linker symbol definition file is called opengl32.lib (regardless of 32 or 64 bit OS version). On GLX/Linux/Unix you directly link against libGL.so, on MacOS X you use the OpenGL *framework*.